# What would be a good way to have users swap products in their order with others on another page in Magento?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

I'm currently trying to build a product replacing functionality to my site. I'm working with a Magento site, and I was wondering what would be a good way to have products be replaced by the users choice.

The plan is that the user can see their order and the items in it. They can click on one of the items which they would like to replace, and then they would be sent to a browsing page to choose a product to replace it with. Once the customer has found a replacement they would be able to select it, and when they hit a button it would replace the initial product they choose to replace.

I currently created an onclick function which would send post data to the browse page, but then I realized if they choose to refresh the page or visit another link the data would be lost. Then I thought of using a session to track the users choices, but I'm not sure how to start the session (without mixing js and php), since the page is not being reloaded. (I could use an ajax request). What would be the most optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Hey Jay, thanks for pushing me in the right direction. I really appreciate it.